# How to join two data frames by group?

Tags: r, join, group-by, dplyr, microbenchmark

I have a data frame (DF) where I have for each CompanyID the Director that worked there in 2006 and 2007 and 2 information about them (Gender and Years old).

```
DF <- 
CompanyID  Name    Country  ISIN     Director_2006 Gender_2006 Yearold_2006  Director_2007 Gender_2007 Yearold_2007   
25830      BANKxxx Austria  AT000504 11734844255        M            54        11734844255        M           55           
25830      BANKxxx Austria  AT000504 187836811559       F            45        5524344997         F           NA           
25830      BANKxxx Austria  AT000504 5524344997         F            NA        5524354997         M           39           
25830      BANKxxx Austria  AT000504 5524354997         M            38        5742347684         M           38           
25830      BANKxxx Austria  AT000504 6613115791         M            41        40160443378        M           30           
12339      BANKyyy Belgium  AT034003 9855321789         M            44        9855321789         M           45           
12339      BANKyyy Belgium  AT034003 277520199          M            NA        23779351           F           34
```

I have a second dataframe (DF2) where I have for each DirectorID (fisrt column) the Years of Experience (third column) for diferent years (second column).

```
DF2 <- 
  DirectorID     Year     YearsExperience
  11734844255    2006        0.4
  11734844255    2007        1.4
  187836811559   2006        1.5  
  5524344997     2006        2.4
  5524344997     2007        3.4
  5524354997     2006        1.8
  5524354997     2007        2.8  
  5742347684     2007        3.5
  40160443378    2007        4.3
  9855321789     2005        2.6
  9855321789     2006        3.6
  9855321789     2007        4.6
  277520199      2006        1.6
  23779351       2007        3.2
  55443322       2005        2.5
  55443322       2006        3.5
```

I would like to join the information of the two data frame, creating a new column with the Years of Experience of each Director from each Company in both years (2006 and 2007), i.e. the columns Experience_2006 and Experience_2007.

Thus, my expected output would look like:

```
DF_final <- 
 CompanyID   Name    Country ISIN       Director_2006  Gender_2006 YearBirth_2006  Experience_2006  Director_2007 Gender_2007 YearBirth_2007 Experience_2007  
 25830      BANKxxx  Austria  AT000504  11734844255          M        54                 0.4         11734844255      M           55                 1.4
 25830      BANKxxx  Austria  AT000504  187836811559         F        45                 1.5         5524344997       F           NA                 3.4
 25830      BANKxxx  Austria  AT000504  5524344997           F        NA                 2.4         5524354997       M           39                 2.8
 25830      BANKxxx  Austria  AT000504  5524354997           M        38                 1.8         5742347684       M           38                 3.5
 25830      BANKxxx  Austria  AT000504  6613115791           M        41                 NA          40160443378      M           30                 4.3
 12339      BANKyyy  Belgium  AT034003  9855321789           M        44                 3.6         9855321789       M           45                 4.6
 12339      BANKyyy  Belgium  AT034003  277520199            M        NA                 1.6         23779351         F           34                 3.2
```

Please, can someone advise me? Thanks.

**DATA**

```
DF <- read.table(text = 
               "CompanyID   Name    Country ISIN     Director_2006  Gender_2006 YearBirth_2006  Director_2007 Gender_2007 YearBirth_2007   
             25830      BANKxxx     Austria  AT000504  11734844255     M        54              11734844255     M           55           
             25830      BANKxxx     Austria  AT000504  187836811559    F        45              5524344997      F           NA           
             25830      BANKxxx     Austria  AT000504    5524344997    F        NA              5524354997      M           39           
             25830      BANKxxx     Austria  AT000504    5524354997    M        38              5742347684      M           38           
             25830      BANKxxx     Austria  AT000504    6613115791    M        41              40160443378     M           30           
             12339      BANKyyy     Belgium  AT034003    9855321789    M        44              9855321789      M           45           
             12339      BANKyyy     Belgium  AT034003     277520199    M        NA                23779351      F           34",
             header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)

DF2 <- read.table(text =
            "DirectorID     Year     YearsExperience
             11734844255    2006        0.4
             11734844255    2007        1.4
             187836811559   2006        1.5  
             5524344997     2006        2.4
             5524344997     2007        3.4
             5524354997     2006        1.8
             5524354997     2007        2.8  
             5742347684     2007        3.5
             40160443378    2007        4.3
             9855321789     2005        2.6
             9855321789     2006        3.6
             9855321789     2007        4.6
             277520199      2006        1.6
             23779351       2007        3.2
             55443322       2005        2.5
             55443322       2006        3.5",
            header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of completion I used `dplyr` and 'tidyr' and made a benchmark with the other functions.

**UPDATE:** I made another version of @Jimbou's answer without using the filter and select functions `myfun4()`. This is the fastest join in my benchmark. Ralf's answer now comes second. My initial version (`myfun3()`) comes third.

```
 microbenchmark::microbenchmark(myfun1(),myfun2(),myfun3(),myfun4())
Unit: milliseconds
     expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq     max neval
 myfun1() 23.1527 28.36865 31.322275 31.53225 33.69430 52.7319   100
 myfun2()  5.2549  5.78445  8.241408  8.25995  9.63870 14.4018   100
 myfun3()  7.9534 10.15115 11.976498 11.40415 13.66255 20.9362   100
 myfun4()  2.9676  3.40105  5.032863  4.87115  5.56065 19.0217   100
```

The code for the functions:

```
myfun4<-function(){
colnames(DF2)[1]='Director_2007'
DF_final<-left_join(DF,DF2[DF2$Year==2006,-2],by='Director_2007') %>% 
              left_join(DF2[DF2$Year==2007,-2],by='Director_2007')
n=dim(DF_final)[2]
colnames(DF_final)[(n-1):n]=paste0('YearsExperience_',2006:2007)
}

myfun3<-function(){
DF2_spread<-tidyr::spread(DF2,Year,YearsExperience)[,-2]
colnames(DF2_spread)=c('Director_2007',paste0('Experience_',colnames(df2_spread)[2:3]))
DF_final<-dplyr::left_join(DF,DF2_spread,by='Director_2007')
}

myfun2<-function() {
  DF1 <- reshape(DF, direction = "long", varying = names(DF)[5:10], sep = "_", timevar = "Year")
DF3 <- merge(DF1, DF2, all.x = TRUE, by.x = c("Director" , "Year"), by.y = c("DirectorID", "Year"))
DF_final<-reshape(DF3, direction = "wide", v.names = names(DF3)[c(1,7,8,10)], timevar = "Year", sep = "_")
}

myfun1<-function(){
  DF %>% 
  left_join(DF2 %>% 
              filter(Year == 2006) %>% 
              select(DirectorID,YearsExperience_2016=YearsExperience), 
            by=c("Director_2006" =  "DirectorID")) %>% 
  left_join(DF2 %>% 
              filter(Year == 2007) %>% 
              select(DirectorID,YearsExperience_2017=YearsExperience), 
            by=c("Director_2007" =  "DirectorID")) 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
library(tidyverse)
DF %>% 
  left_join(DF2 %>% 
              filter(Year == 2006) %>% 
              select(DirectorID,YearsExperience_2016=YearsExperience), 
            by=c("Director_2006" =  "DirectorID")) %>% 
  left_join(DF2 %>% 
              filter(Year == 2007) %>% 
              select(DirectorID,YearsExperience_2017=YearsExperience), 
            by=c("Director_2007" =  "DirectorID")) 
  CompanyID    Name Country     ISIN Director_2006 Gender_2006 YearBirth_2006 Director_2007 Gender_2007
1     25830 BANKxxx Austria AT000504   11734844255           M             54   11734844255           M
2     25830 BANKxxx Austria AT000504  187836811559           F             45    5524344997           F
3     25830 BANKxxx Austria AT000504    5524344997           F             NA    5524354997           M
4     25830 BANKxxx Austria AT000504    5524354997           M             38    5742347684           M
5     25830 BANKxxx Austria AT000504    6613115791           M             41   40160443378           M
6     12339 BANKyyy Belgium AT034003    9855321789           M             44    9855321789           M
7     12339 BANKyyy Belgium AT034003     277520199           M             NA      23779351           F
  YearBirth_2007 YearsExperience_2016 YearsExperience_2017
1             55                  0.4                  1.4
2             NA                  1.5                  3.4
3             39                  2.4                  2.8
4             38                  1.8                  3.5
5             30                   NA                  4.3
6             45                  3.6                  4.6
7             34                  1.6                  3.2
```

Comment: This way works well! But the problem is that my real data is bigger than this. My file DF has 3160 observations with 48 variables (my Years are from 2006 to 2016). My file DF2 has 30900 observations (with all Directors and Years of Experience I need ). Do you know an efficient way to run this script? Because I tried using this and R aborted your script for lack of memory.

Comment: yeah then don't use this answer and check out my benchmark (below in the answers): Ralf's or my answer should then be the fastest way for you. The `filter` and `select`-functions from `dplyr` slow down the execution time *a lot*.

Answer (score 1):

Using base R functions:

```
DF1 <- reshape(DF, direction = "long", varying = names(DF)[5:10], sep = "_", timevar = "Year")
DF3 <- merge(DF1, DF2, all.x = TRUE, by.x = c("Director" , "Year"), by.y = c("DirectorID", "Year"))
reshape(DF3, direction = "wide", v.names = names(DF3)[c(1,7,8,10)], timevar = "Year", sep = "_")    
#>    CompanyID    Name Country     ISIN id Director_2007 Gender_2007
#> 1      12339 BANKyyy Belgium AT034003  7      23779351           F
#> 3      25830 BANKxxx Austria AT000504  3    5524354997           M
#> 4      25830 BANKxxx Austria AT000504  2    5524344997           F
#> 5      25830 BANKxxx Austria AT000504  4    5742347684           M
#> 8      25830 BANKxxx Austria AT000504  5   40160443378           M
#> 9      12339 BANKyyy Belgium AT034003  6    9855321789           M
#> 11     25830 BANKxxx Austria AT000504  1   11734844255           M
#>    YearBirth_2007 YearsExperience_2007 Director_2006 Gender_2006
#> 1              34                  3.2     277520199           M
#> 3              39                  2.8    5524344997           F
#> 4              NA                  3.4  187836811559           F
#> 5              38                  3.5    5524354997           M
#> 8              30                  4.3    6613115791           M
#> 9              45                  4.6    9855321789           M
#> 11             55                  1.4   11734844255           M
#>    YearBirth_2006 YearsExperience_2006
#> 1              NA                  1.6
#> 3              NA                  2.4
#> 4              45                  1.5
#> 5              38                  1.8
#> 8              41                   NA
#> 9              44                  3.6
#> 11             54                  0.4
```